# Jasper Studio bar chart y axis intervals

Tags: jasper-reports, bar-chart

I think, I encountered an interesting bug in Jasperstudio (6.3). At the belove chart, there is 8 intervals from 0 to 2. Some of the numbers are repeated. (0,0,0,1,1,2,2,2). I want to use only integer numbers on my chart. So, what can be the solution and how can I set any property to display y values as 0,1,2,3,...  I noticed that it divides the range 8 intervals as 0,0.25,0.5,0.75,1.0,1.25,1.5,1.75,2.0, and gets the integer values of the points.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Set the [net.sf.jasperreports.chart.range.axis.integer.unit](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/config.reference.html#net.sf.jasperreports.chart.range.axis.integer.unit) property to `true` for the chart element.

It should look something like this in the JRXML:

```
                <chart>
                    <reportElement ...>
                        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.chart.range.axis.integer.unit" value="true"/>
                    </reportElement>
```

Comment: It had no effect for me